# React TS - Passing props up the component tree

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have created form elements that I can configure in different ways to create forms.

Here's an example of that:

```
<form>
  <Label htmlFor="name" name="Enter name:" />
  <InputWrapper>
    <Input id="name" name="name" />
  </InputWrapper>
  <CharacterLimit />
</form>
```

What I would like to do is set a `maxLength` & `required` `prop` on my `Input` component and it will cause my `Label` component to then have a red asterisk( * ) and my `CharacterLimit` component to display the `maxLength` set on my `Input` component.

Here's what my `Label` component looks like:

```
interface ILabel {
  htmlFor: string;
  name: string;
  required?: boolean;
}

export const Label: React.FC<ILabel> = ({ htmlFor, name, required }) => {
  return (
    <StyledLabel htmlFor={htmlFor}>
      {name} {required && <StyledRequired>*</StyledRequired>}
    </StyledLabel>
  );
};

const StyledLabel = styled.label`
  font-weight: 600;
`;
const StyledRequired = styled.span`
  color: red;
`;
```

And here's what my CharacterLimit components look like:

```
interface ICharacterLimit {
  maxLength?: number;
}

export const CharacterLimit: React.FC<ICharacterLimit> = ({ maxLength }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {maxLength && (
        <StyledCharacterLimit>0 / {maxLength} Characters</StyledCharacterLimit>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

> Now you're probably wondering why I don't just put the `Label` &
>   `CharacterLimit` components inside of my `Input` component and
>   conditionally render them that way.

Well, I have another component as you can see called `InputWrapper`, this is used to style the "container" of the `input`, the reason I wanted to make this styling separate, is so then I could put an `input` and a `button` inside of the container for example.

Here's an illustration to example better what I mean:

[image]

How can I get the props passed from my `Input` component to the `Label` and `CharacterLimit` components? Or is there another approach to achieve them the same layouts in my illustration?

I have put together a demo on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-wave-h0yj4)

Comment: All of your child components are in the same file then what is the problem?

Comment: @JaredSmith Could you give any examples of how you would approach it to gain the same layout? I'm still learning React so some practical examples I can see / play with would be great!

Comment: I just re-read the question a little more deeply. I retract the earlier comment. I think now that the issue you are having is due to trying to make this too generic (code reuse!). There's no harm in making each of these very specific one-off components that do exactly the layout you want (I still think validation should happen at the form level and be passed down in props). I think trying to make your style wrappers generic and composable will be more trouble than it ends up being worth. The data flow in the end will look like this:

Comment: form model -> isValid?, callback to wrapper -> renders input with callback -> input.onChange -> callback from form model passed as props -> updates model -> gets validated -> passes isValid? back to wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily an answer, but too long for comment

Something like this:

```
const FormModel = () => {
  const [formModel, setFormModel] = useState();
  const updateFormModel = name => value => setFormModel({
    ...formModel,
    { [name]: value }
  });
  return (
    <form>
      <InputWrapper onChange={updateForm("something")} isValid={validate(formModel)} />
    <form>
  );
};

const InputWrapper = ({ onChange, isValid }) => {
  // returns appropriate stuff, including 
  // <input onChange={e => onChange(e.currentTarget.value)} />
  // styled based on isValid prop. May also want to debounce
  // input, but whateves.
}
```

Comment: Would you mind forking my SandBox? I learn better from being able to play and see something working in action. Comments would be appreciated too :)